# Translation Manager - extracting multimedia files or not?

Tags: 2011, cme, content-manager, translation-manager

When someone in SDL Tridion UI clicks on "Translate", if the selected component to translate is a multimedia (doc, pdf, etc.) will that actual file data(binary) be trasferred to the TMS for translation too, or only the "metadata" fields will be transferred?

**Are the binaries (pdf, doc, xls, etc) extracted and managed by the Translation Manager/TMS automaticaly** or they are not?

Thanks,
bvl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the following restrictions apply to Multimedia Components:

- Only the name and metadata of a Multimedia Component is sent for
  translation, not the binary content
- Only SDL Tridion metadata is sent for External Content Library (ECL) Multimedia Components
- You cannot add ECL Multimedia Components directly to a Translation Job; you need to add them to a Page or a Bundle and send that for translation

Take into account, that the metadata fields are sent for translation, only if they are marked as **translatable**

Comment: Hi Puntero, I tried submitting Tridion components with binary data and noticed that only metadata (text fields marked "Translatable") were sent to Translation management system. Does Tridion Translation Manager support translation of  PDF/Multimedia items?

Answer (score 1):

No, just the metadata fields that have been marked as `Translatable` are sent to TMS. For instance if you have an image and you have metadata for `Title` and `Alternative Text`, just those fields are sent if they are marked as `Translatable`

Comment: Eric, where to mark the field Translatable? In schema? This "switch" is available in Tridion only after the Tranlsation Manager is installed? Thanks!

Comment: Yes on both--the `Translatable` option is at a field level in Schemas and after Translation Manager is installed.